# Visualizing weights of trained Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I trained a model in TF an I would like to visualize its weights. Below is the code that I used to train the model. It looks like a lot of code but it's very straight forward. I just build the network, define the placeholders and train it with the optimize() function.

```
# Create the neural network
  def conv_net(x, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):

# Define a scope for reusing the variables
    with tf.variable_scope('ConvNet', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):

    # Reshape to match picture format [Height x Width x Channel]
    # Tensor input become 4-D: [Batch Size, Height, Width, Channel]
    #x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, height, width, channels])

    # -- FIRST BLOCK --
    # Two convolutional layers with 32 filters, size of 5, padding = 'same'
    # One max-pool layer 2X2
    # One dropout layer
      conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='SAME', name='conv1')
      conv1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv1,training=training)
      conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, 32, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='SAME', name='conv2')
      conv2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv2, training=training)
      conv2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, 2, 2)
      conv2 = tf.layers.dropout(conv2, rate=dropout)

    # -- SECOND BLOCK --
    # Two convolutional layers with 32 filters, size of 3, padding = 'same'
    # One max-pool layer 2X2
    # One dropout layer with 1.5 dropout rate
      conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv2, 32, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='SAME', name='conv3')
      conv3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv3, training=training)
      conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv3, 32, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='SAME', name='conv4')
      conv4 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv4, training=training)
      conv4 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv4, 2, 2)
      conv4 = tf.layers.dropout(conv4, rate=dropout*1.25)

    # Flatten the data to a 1-D vector for fully connected layers
      fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv4)

    # -- THIRD BLOCK --
    # Two fully connected layers with 1024 neurons
    # 2x dropout rate on each layer
      fc1 = tf.layers.dense(fc1, 1024)
      fc1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(fc1, training=training)
      fc1 = tf.layers.dropout(fc1, rate=dropout*2)
      fc2 = tf.layers.dense(fc1, 1024)
      fc2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(fc2, training=training)
      fc2 = tf.layers.dropout(fc2, rate=dropout*2)

    # Output layer
      out = tf.layers.dense(fc2, num_classes)

  return out

#### Misc stuff tu run train part ####
# Predicted classes
logits_out = conv_net(images_placeholder, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)

y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits_out, name='y_pred')
y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

y_true_cls = tf.argmax(labels_placeholder, axis=1)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_out,      labels=labels_placeholder)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

optimizer =  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_pred_cls, y_true_cls)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

#Optimizer
def optimize(epochs):

  start_time = time.time()

  for i in range(epochs):

    indices = np.random.choice(trainX.shape[0], batch_size)
    x_batch, y_true_batch = trainX[indices], trainY[indices]

    batch_norm_update = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

    session.run([optimizer, batch_norm_update],  feed_dict={images_placeholder:x_batch,
                                                            labels_placeholder: y_true_batch,
                                                            training: True})

    saver.save(session, 'C:\\Users\\ggiorcelli\\Tensorflow Workbooks\\animals_model') 


    if (i+1) % 10 == 0:
        train_accuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={images_placeholder: x_batch, 
                                                          labels_placeholder: y_true_batch,
                                                          training: True})

        indices_test = np.random.choice(testX.shape[0], batch_size)
        images_test = testX[indices_test]
        labels_test = testY[indices_test]

        test_accuracy = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={images_placeholder: images_test, 
                                                         labels_placeholder: labels_test,
                                                         training: True})

        print('Step {:3d}: training accuracy = {:0.3f}, test accuracy = {:0.3f}'.format(i+1, train_accuracy, test_accuracy))

  end_time = time.time()
  time_dif = end_time - start_time

  print("Time usage: " + str(timedelta(seconds=int(round(time_dif)))))

#Train
with tf.Session() as session:
  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  session.run(init, {training:True})
  optimize(epochs=200)
```

With this code I'm able to train the model successfully.
Now, I would like to get the weights of the convolutional layer. To do so, I use this code snippet:

```
with tf.variable_scope('conv1', reuse=True):
  w1 = tf.get_variable('weights')
  x_image = tf.reshape(w1, [5, 5, 1, 32])
  img = tf.summary.image('img',x_image)
```

However with the code above I only get an image object that I cannot visualize. I'm not even sure if this is the right way to get the weights. I've seen that other people have asked this question but most answers lead to Tensorboard and I want to do this is in an iPython shell.

Below is an example of what I would like to see.

[Conv Layer Weights 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iesP.png)

[Conv Layer Weights 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZZLm.png)

Comment: we're impressed you "read every post on this site".   what would you want the the visualization to look like?

Comment: @ShpielMeister I edited my question with a couple of examples of what I would like to visualize